Paskening from a Daas Yachid vs Daas Rabim
Is following a majority in Halacha a must? Is it looked down upon, or Asur to follow a minority opinion? If so; why?
I would be interesting in seeing examples/Sources of times we follow a daas Yachid in Halacha or Hashkafa, over the majority opinion.

See the shach at the end of yoreh deah 242 where he has klalim of pesak where he discusses this.

Were it forbidden to follow minority opinions, we would have all coalesced to one practice long ago.

Besides the Great Sanhedrin, the majority of "what" opinions? How many rabbis do you poll? What geographic area/historical timespan do you consider rabbis authoritative for you?

For example it would seem most of the Chariedi world follows the Daas Yachid of the Besht regarding what Hashgacha is... just as one example
